# SQL Consultas tablas relacionadas Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

no se como resolver estas dos consultas:

[image]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La primera consulta sería así? no hay alguna otra manera de ponerlo que sesa 3 meses exacto, lo digo por los 30,31s

```
SELECT ID_PRODUCTO FROM PRODUCTOS 
    WHERE ID_PRODUCTO IN ( SELECT ID_PRODUCTO FROM PEDIDOS 
                        WHERE FECHA>SYSDATE-90)
```

Comment: Deberías de leer esto: [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/)

Comment: He editado, perdona, pero la última no tengo mucha idea

Comment: sería bueno que hicieras una pregunta por consulta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La 6 seria algo asi:

`select * from PRODUCTOS left join PEDIDOS on PRODUCTOS.ID_PRODUCTO = PEDIDOS.ID_PRODUCTO where month(PEDIDOS.FECHA)>9;`

La 7:

`select sum(PEDIDOS.CANT), count(PEDIDOS.ID_PEDIDO) from PEDIDOS inner join PRODUCTOS on PEDIDOS.ID_PRODUCTO = PRODUCTOS.ID_PRODUCTO where PRODUCTOS.DESCRIPCION = "Televisor M1";`

Comment: sirve esta columna en oracle? month?

Comment: Creo que si, aunque creo que hay varios tipos de formatos date segun este configurada la tabla, nose si ira con todos

Comment: Muchas gracias, los inner joint en oracle seria tabla.id=tabla.id y los left joint  tabla.id(+)=tabla.id ?? creo recordar

Comment: De nada. Me parece que en oracle los inner join tambien funcionan, aunque no estoi seguro

Comment: Ivan, mira [answer]. Ademas trata de no contestar preguntas que no cumplen con los requisitos minimos del sitio (haber intentando algo, no poner imagenes del codigo ni la pregunta)